# Citation, author et al (in the text), all authors in the References in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, babel

I want to have (author et al year) in my text, but in the Reference section all the authors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxnames=1,uniquelist=false, 
            language=english, autolang=other]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib1.bib} 

\begin{document}

\par{Επίσης, η μηχανική αποτριβή που λαμβάνει χώρα στις 
ολισθαίνουσες επιφάνειες των δοντιών κατά την μάσηση των τροφών ή 
κατά την σύγκλειση, έχει ως αποτέλεσμα την απομάκρυνση των 
προϊόντων χημικής αποδόμησης αλλά και επιτάχυνσης της εκ’ νέου διάβρωσής\index{διάβρωση} 
τους. Επομένως, η χημική αποδόμηση εξαρτάται ουσιαστικά εξίσου από 
τη διάχυση \selectlanguage{english}{(diffusion)} 
\selectlanguage{greek}των χημικών ουσιών στην επιφάνεια των 
σύνθετων ρητινών αλλά και από την ταχύτητα με την οποία στη 
συνέχεια αυτές απομακρύνονται. Η διάχυση με τη σειρά της εξαρτάται από 
ποικίλες παραμέτρους, όπως η σύσταση της ρητίνης, ο βαθμός 
μετατροπής των διπλών δεσμών, ο σιλανιούχος παράγοντας και η κ.ο.\% φόρτιση σε ενισχυτικές ουσίες\selectlanguage{english} \parencite{Soderholm}.}\selectlanguage{greek} 


\end{document}



@article{Soderholm,
    Author = {S{\"o}derholm and Yang MC and Garcea I},
    Date-Added = {2015-08-09 17:30:35 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2018-03-29 23:55:17 +0000},
    Journal = {Eur J Oral Sci.},
    Number = {6},
    Pages = {555-560},
    Title = {Filler particle leachability of experimental dental composite},
    Volume = {108},
    Year = {2000}}
```

[image: reference in the text]

[image: References]

Comment: Off-topic: `\par` does not take an argument.

Comment: Instead of `maxnames=1` use `maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=99`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this. I've corrected several other errors in your document as well:

- `\par{}` is all wrong. Just type your paragraphs separated by a blank line. No need to use `\par` at all (which does not take an argument as @Mico points out in the comments)
- For just a short piece of text in English you should use `\foreigntext{english}{(diffusion)}` instead of two `\selectlanguage` commands.
- I don't think you need to wrap the citation command in `\selectlanguage`. I think `biblatex` handles this for you as you have specified `language=english` in its options.
- It's probably not essential, but often wise to load `csquotes` for multilingual documents.
- And to answer your actual question, you can independently control the maximum number of names used in citations and bibliography using `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames`. Using `maxnames` just sets both of these other options to the same.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Soderholm,
  Author = {S{\"o}derholm and Yang MC and Garcea I},
  Journal = {Eur J Oral Sci.},
  Number = {6},
  Pages = {555-560},
  Title = {Filler particle leachability of experimental dental composite},
  Volume = {108},
  Year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxcitenames=1,maxbibnames=99,uniquelist=false, 
            language=english, autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Επίσης, η μηχανική αποτριβή που λαμβάνει χώρα στις ολισθαίνουσες επιφάνειες
των δοντιών κατά την μάσηση των τροφών ή κατά την σύγκλειση, έχει ως
αποτέλεσμα την απομάκρυνση των προϊόντων χημικής αποδόμησης αλλά και
επιτάχυνσης της εκ’ νέου διάβρωσής τους. Επομένως, η χημική αποδόμηση
εξαρτάται ουσιαστικά εξίσου από τη διάχυση
\foreignlanguage{english}{(diffusion)} των χημικών ουσιών στην επιφάνεια των
σύνθετων ρητινών αλλά και από την ταχύτητα με την οποία στη συνέχεια αυτές
απομακρύνονται. Η διάχυση με τη σειρά της εξαρτάται από ποικίλες παραμέτρους,
όπως η σύσταση της ρητίνης, ο βαθμός μετατροπής των διπλών δεσμών, ο
σιλανιούχος παράγοντας και η κ.ο.\% φόρτιση σε ενισχυτικές ουσίες
\autocite{Soderholm}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right but it kind of a habit as for the \par. On the other hand, I wrap the citation command in \selectlanguage because when i didn't I got a latin letters citation and when I wrap it with \selectlanguage it solve it..As for my question I didn't knew it and I was struggling with the bib file...